# How to remove port from url angular2?

Tags: angular, npm, angular2-routing, angular-cli

When I run any angular2 project by default it add **localhost:4200** , even after installing on server it is showing that.

How can we remove the port from URL? I prefer a solution where I don't have to change the core files.

I have also tried this on package.json,but it is not working:

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve --port 80",
  ...
}
```

P.S-> I have already looked through other similar questions, but they don't solve my problem.

Comment: You can put a local domain

Comment: If this is a production server - do not use `ng serve`, it's designed for development only. Build your code and then deploy the static files to something like Apache/NGINX.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an angular issue, even if you remove it the browser assumes the server is running on port 80.

You should try to use a virtual host . Depending your OS it's pretty easy to use it.

Comment: Yes, I understand , right now i`m making changes in core files to set the port 80.